# Domain Controller Not Found with Two DNS Address

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I'm experiencing a problem on some windows clients connecting a Domain Controller.

The domain controller is 192.168.10.240 and the client have the following DNS configuration :

- DNS 1 : 192.168.10.240
- DNS 2 : 8.8.8.8 (google)

Sometimes, some client cannot find the Domain Controller, it's like they are only searching on the second DNS (google) and cannot find my controller. If I remove the Google DNS it will find the DC correctly.

Why is this happening and how can I force to search 192.168.10.240 and use 8.8.8.8 if the first is down ?
Is there something else I can try ?

Thank you for you help,
Sebastien

Comment: Active Directory domain clients should NEVER use DNS servers other than those that hold your AD DNS zones. Remove 8.8.8.8 from your clients and be done with it.

Comment: (adding to Joe's comment) And get a second domain controller with DNS, then you'll have a good secondary.

Comment: If you insist on using google for queries to public DNS, configure 8.8.8.8 as forwarders on the DC